# Undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.refs.myVideo.seek(0)') React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-video-controls component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video-controls) which is based off react-native-video(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video)  and I am trying to play the next video in a sequence and have that video seek to 0 (so it plays from the beginning). But I am getting the error: "Undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.refs.myVideo.seek(0)') React-Native"

Here is my code:

```
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import VideoPlayer from 'react-native-video-controls';


export default class Player extends Component {
constructor(props){
  this.state = {
    playlist: [require(file1.mp4),require(file2.mp4)]
  }
 }
  playNext() {
    this.refs.myVideo.seek(0);
    let playlist = this.state.playlist;
    playlist.shift();
    this.setState({playlist,})
}
render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <VideoPlayer
          ref='myVideo'
          muted={false}
          seekColor={ 'red' }
          source={this.state.playlist[0]}
          navigator={ this.props.navigator }
          style={styles.player}
          onEnd={()=>this.playNext()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

what am I doing wrong

Edit: this is for android btw

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the ref should look like: `ref={this.myVideo}`
When you are using VideoPlayer Video methods are deeper, so you should write: `this.myVideo.player.ref.seek(0)` (VideoPlayer is a container for Video)